# Permutation ends with an odd number

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In permutations of $\{0,1,1,3\}$, how many end with an odd number?

By testing via programming, I can conclude that the result is $\frac{A(4,4)}{A(2,2)} \cdot \frac{3}{4}$.

But, to my intuition, since we already divide $A(2,2)$, the result seems to be $2/3$, because there are $2$ odds in $0,1,3$.

So, how to prove the result is $\frac{A(4,4)}{A(2,2)} \cdot \frac{3}{4}$ better in an intuitive way.

Comment: how many end with odd (???) $\to$ how many end with *an odd number* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four positions to fill.  If a permutation is to end with an odd number, the only zero must be in one of the first three positions.  By symmetry, $3/4$ of the permutations of the numbers in the multiset $\{0, 1, 1, 3\}$ will have an odd number in the last position.

We can verify this by counting the number of permutations with and without the restriction that the last number is odd.

If the last number must be odd, there are three ways to place the $0$ since it must be in one of the first three positions.  That leaves three ways to place the $3$.  The two ones must fill the remaining two positions.  Hence, there are $3 \cdot 3 = 9$ permutations of the numbers in the multiset $\{0, 1, 1, 3\}$ which have an odd number in the last position.

If there were no restrictions, we could place the $0$ in four ways and the $3$ in three ways.  The other two positions must be filled with ones.  Hence, there are $4 \cdot 3 = 12$ permutations of the numbers in the multiset $\{0, 1, 1, 3\}$.

Since $9/12 = 3/4$, it is indeed the case that $3/4$ of the permutations of the numbers in the multiset $\{0, 1, 1, 3\}$ end in an odd number.

I suspect that the source of your confusion is that there are only three distinct numbers in the permutation.  However, we have to account for the number of ways we can place the zero among the four positions in the permutation.